# Can I prevent the screen from turning on for an incoming phone call?

Tags: android

I have seen questions that are somewhat similar to this, but none that answer this question.  If I wanted to be able to prevent the screen from turning on at all when receiving an incoming call, is this possible?  I know it may sound bizarre, but it would only act this way exactly when the user would want it to, particularly at night, and they would be well aware of this behavior.

I'd still want it to turn on if they pressed the unlock button of course, just not when receiving an incoming call.

I've experimented with Screen Brightness and Screen Timeout, but it still turns on the screen while the call is ringing.  I would like it to act similarly to when you receive a notification message, where you see the blinking indicator, but the screen never turns on.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help, I appreciate it!
Paul

Comment: <rant> did you, by any chance, find a solution? i would so love to stop accidentally picking and refusing calls when dragging the phone from my pocket, and when its set to never turn screen off....well...it never turns it off after a missed call. I found an app that at least replaces the slide to accept screen, but it doesnt quite cut it and i cant find its source. </rant>

Comment: Sorry, I did not find a solution to this, which is unfortunate, because it does have some good purposes like yours and mine.  It would be a nice addition in the future.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why do you need this?

I don't think it's possible, a malicious app could hide calls. Using the unlock button during a call would also interfere with existing functions, (muting the ringer without hanging up). If you don't want to receive calls, turn on the airplane mode but I guess this isn't what you need.

(fun fact: on a Nexus One, the trackball blinks white while receiving a call so turning off the screen wouldn't matter, it would still light up the whole room...)

Comment: I do understand that it sounds strange out of context, but the reason I want it to do this is for certain people who call during the night that are predetermined to go to voicemail. The way it works now is that the screen still turns on.  So, there wouldn't be the issue of muting the ringer without hanging up, etc. since they're going to voicemail. It would be completely customizable to only happen for the people they chose. I understand the potential for malicious apps, but that is the case now as well, and ratings and comments would hopefully quickly catch those types. Thanks for the input.